# How to Binding Hidden Value of input type = hidden to the model in Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular

Here i am creating a listing form where the user can list there data after logging into the website.I want to add username also when the user submit the form.In the listing form i have used a input type=hidden in which i have put the username.
I want to add this username value to my lisitng  model and pass the value of model to the database
I want to bind the value of hidden field of my template driven form to the model of my angular application

I am getting this username from the api

Below is my angular6 template driven form

```
<form #listingForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(listingForm)" style="margin-top:100px">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" style="padding-top:35px;margin:0 auto;box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px 0px rgba(102,102,102,0.73);">
        <h3 style="color:black">Add Your Listing Here</h3>
       
        <hr>
        <div *ngIf="userClaims">
        <input type="hidden" #Username="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="userClaims.Username" [value]="list.Username" name="Username">
      </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-top:50px;">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <label for="">Business Name</label>
            <input type="text" #BName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="list.BName" name="BName">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="">Business Tagline</label>
             <input type="text" #BTagline="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="list.BTagline" name="BTagline">
             </div>
            
        </div>
        


        <div class="clearfix">

          <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" >Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Below is my **listing.model.ts**

```
    export class Listing {
   
    }
```

I am getting the Username from the other services of my application

Answer (score 0):

why don't you assign userClaims.Username to `list.Username` in `ts` file itself and make it simple

```
<input type="hidden" #Username="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="list.Username" name="Username">
```

You can remove the above hidden input also since it will not impact on anything.

Comment: i just want to save the username by default...btw its not working

Comment: i don't want to give any extra box for writing usernane when user is already logged in

Comment: Thats why I said, you can remove the hidden element as well.

Comment: can't able to assign userClaims.Username to list.Username in ts file

Answer (score 0):

By Using the below method i am able to bind the value

```
<input type="hidden" #Username="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="userClaims.Username" 
 name="Username">
```